# QTableView not scrolling when mouse is at disabled delegate button

Tags: qt, scroll, pyside, qtableview, qstyleditemdelegate

**Setup description**

- Table in PySide created with
  QMainWindow - > QWidget -> QTableView -> TableModel (QAbstractTableModel) -> array[[]]
- For second column is created ButtonDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate)

**Problem description**
If button in delegate is disabled [setEnabled(False)], the scrolling of table is not working when mouse is above the disabled button.

**Other**

- When buttons are enabled,everything works well.
- In my application, I'm enabling/disabling buttons based on the data.
- Scrolling should work in any case, because otherwise the functionality is not user friendly, when scrolling is not working at one of the table columns - with disabled button(s).
- I tried few things with eventFilter but nothing worked.

Tested with PySide6 (6.2.2.1), Python 3.9, Windows 10, Debian

Possibly the same problem (but no solution listed):
https://forum.qt.io/topic/123495/disabled-widget-hogs-scrollevents-how-to-disable

Minimal functioning example:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout 
from PySide6.QtWidgets import  QTableView, QWidget, QStyledItemDelegate, QPushButton
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QModelIndex, QAbstractTableModel, QItemSelectionModel

class ButtonDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)    

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        self.parent().openPersistentEditor(index)
        super(ButtonDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QPushButton("Button", parent)
        editor.setEnabled(False)
        return editor

class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, localData=[[]], parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.modelData = localData

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                return "Row " + str(section)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.modelData[0])

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.modelData)

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            col = index.column()
            return self.modelData[row][col]

app = QApplication()

data = [['1', '2'],['1', '2'],['1', '2'],['1', '2'],['1', '2'],['1', '2'],['1', '2'],
    ['1', '2'],['1', '2'],['1', '2'],['1', '2'],['1', '2'],['1', '2'],['1', '2'],
    ['1', '2'],['1', '2'],['1', '2'],['1', '2']]

model = TableModel(data)

tableView = QTableView()
tableView.setModel(model)
selectionModel = QItemSelectionModel(model)
tableView.setSelectionModel(selectionModel)
tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, ButtonDelegate(tableView))


widget = QWidget()
widget.horizontalHeader = tableView.horizontalHeader()
widget.horizontalHeader.setStretchLastSection(True)
widget.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
widget.mainLayout.setContentsMargins(1,1,1,1)
widget.mainLayout.addWidget(tableView)
widget.setLayout(widget.mainLayout)

mainWindow = QMainWindow()
mainWindow.setCentralWidget(widget)
mainWindow.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 300)
mainWindow.show()

exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this with PyQt6 so I can confirm that it's related to Qt6

The difference is that a `Wheel` event is always *accepted* on disabled buttons in Qt6 while it's ignored on Qt5, and it's related to the special behavior of QAbstractButton for input events. This has been actually considered a wrong behavior for Qt5, so it cannot be considered a bug (see [QTBUG-79102](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-79102) and [QTBUG-67032](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-67032)).

The solution is to set the set the event as *not* accepted in the event filter of the delegate, and return `True` to propagate the event to the parent:

```
class ButtonDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == event.Type.Wheel:
            event.setAccepted(False)
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```

<sup>Note that opening the editor in the `paint` function is not a good idea: while the function usually is "ignored" when the editor is already open, any operation that can cause repaint (and, potentially, geometry changes) should *never* happen inside painting functions.</sup>